# maven release git push uses incorrect URL

Tags: git, maven

I've been googling this problem for hours without finding a match.  I have a (bare) git repo at ~/my-repo.git.  My working clone of that repo is at /development/checkout/...  There are multiple projects in the root of the repo,one of which (my-project) is checked out at /development/checkout/my-project and when I call

```
mvn release:prepare
```

from /development/checkout/my-project everything starts fine then dies at the git push with the message:

```
[ERROR] fatal: '/home/mike/my-repo.git/my-project' does not appear to be a git repository
```

Which is absolutely correct - in fact that directory does not exist, and I can see from the output that Maven is invoking git to push to that path.  The <scm/> node in the POM is:

```
<scm>
    <developerConnection>scm:git:file:///home/mike/my-repo.git</developerConnection>
</scm>
```

so why does Maven insist on appending '/my-project' to that URL and making it invalid?  Doubtless this is a config issue rather than a bug, but I'm struggling to find the relevant nugget of documentation.

Maven 3.0.5

git 1.8.2.1

maven-release-plugin 2.4.1

Thanks,
Mike

Comment: Do you have "my-project" anywhere in your pom.xml? Need more context.

Comment: I'm having exactly the same issue - it's appending the artifactId to the repo url. Have you found an answer?